# How could I implement AND search filter

Tags: swift

I implements OR filter,

if user types "NBA LA",
Any item in this array "appDel.dataFetcher?.appTitles" will be searched with OR mode.

However, I don't know how to implement AND mode.

That is any selected item must have NBA and LA in its text at the same time

## OR SEARCH

```
        let searchTerms = searchController.searchBar.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        for term: String in searchTerms {
            let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", term)
            let array = ((appDel.dataFetcher?.appTitles)! as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
            searchResult += array as! [String]
        }
        let mySet = Set<String>(searchResult)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up your resulting **AND** predicate using [`NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCompoundPredicate/andPredicateWithSubpredicates:) like below:

```
let predicates = searchTerms.map {
  return NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", $0)
}
let searchPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
let searchResult = ((appDel.dataFetcher?.appTitles)! as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
let mySet = Set<String>(searchResult)
```

FYI, you can split your text much more easier using `componentsSeparatedByString`:

```
let searchTerms = searchController.searchBar.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```